# Want to delete entire column if it has <30 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple columns and multiple rows (>200 rows). i would like to delete entire column if any of the column has <30 rows data. Please help

```
Sub Delete_EntireColumn()
Dim iCntr
    For iCntr = 1 To 10 Step 1
        Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Sub Delete_EntireColumn()
Dim LCol as Long, LRow as Long, i as Long

With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF)

    LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = LCol To 1 Step - 1
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        If LRow < 30 Then
            .Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

In case the rows are not consecutively filled:

```
Sub Delete_EntireColumn()
Dim LCol as Long, LRow as Long, i as Long

With Workbooks(REF).Sheets(REF)

    LCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = LCol To 1 Step - 1
        LRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(i))
        If LRow < 30 Then
            .Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit` and declare all variables properly: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*. • Here it should be `Dim LCol As Long, i As Long, LRow As Long`

Comment: Plus1: a lot of people don't remember the `Step -1` part of `FOR` :). I would however suggest to have the `Worksheet` object passed to the UDF that way it becomes dynamic

Comment: `Step - 1` saves you from a lot of headaches if you want to delete any list of objects. Very useful indeed. It does not appear OP made a `UDF` but I would agree.

Comment: thank you Tim, its working but if the rows has values in few top and bottom rows its not deleting. there are total 200 rows but some of the columns has blank cells in between, i would like to delete those columns

Comment: @sunil replace `LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row` with `LRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(i))` if you want to count only cells that contain data.

Comment: Hey Tim and Peh you both are great, its working perfectly, you guys saved my time, than you again

Comment: Glad to have helped